# Image appears different on Android Marshmallow and Android Nougat

Tags: android, image, imageview, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-7.0-nougat

I had the .svg file of my logo. I used the vector assets in android studio to convert svg file into an xml file. Now when i use the xml file in an image view. Devices that have Nougat display the image perfectly but devices that have Marshmallow and lower display a different image.

This is how it should look like and how it appears in devices with Android Nougat

[image]
But this is how it looks on devices with Android Marshmallow.

[image]

Here is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_logo"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_20"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_20"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvOnlineTailor"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/text"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        />

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

How to fix this problem?
I know i can use a png image instead of xml file but i dont want the image to pixelate.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share your ImageView XML?

Comment: Can you try with support library? https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources.html#vector-drawables-backward-solution

Answer (score -1):

Try to use
`app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_logo"`
instead of
`android:src="@drawable/ic_logo"`

Cheers.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).